# Android Kotlin load only one more element to recyclerview problem

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to load just one element with one scroll gesture. Now it is like one scroll gesture loads 1 or few new elements (depends on time of scroll gesture). As a solution I could do this gesture in shorter time than 500ms or make this postDelayed's delay longer but I guess there are better solutions for that. Do you have any ideas how to do that?

This app is written in MVP pattern. Here is my code:

CurrencyFragmentList.kt

```
private fun addScrollerListener() {
    rvItem.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(_rvItem: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(_rvItem, newState)
            Log.e("scroll", isLoading.toString())
            if (!isLoading) {
                if (!_rvItem.canScrollVertically(1)) {

                    loadMore()
                    isLoading = true
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

private fun loadMore() {
    showProgressDialog()
    var numberOfDays = mainPresenter.getNumberOfMinusDays()
    numberOfDays++
    mainPresenter.saveNumberOfMinusDaysIntoSp(numberOfDays)
    var dateMinusXDays = mainPresenter.currentDateMinusXDaysToStr(numberOfDays)


    val nextLimit = listSize + 1
    for (i in listSize until nextLimit) {

        if (mainPresenter.checkIfSuchDateExistsinSp(dateMinusXDays)) {
            Log.d("such date already exists in shared prefs", dateMinusXDays)
            handler.postDelayed({
                mainPresenter.processDateWithoutMakingACall(dateMinusXDays)
            }, 500)
        } else {     
            mainPresenter.makeACall(dateMinusXDays)
            Log.d("retrofit call made", dateMinusXDays)
        }
    }
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun hideProgressDialog() {
    if (apiResponseList.size > 1) {
        apiResponseList.removeAt(apiResponseList.size - 1)
        listSize = apiResponseList.size
        itemAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(listSize)
    } else progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE

    isLoading = false
}

override fun assignResponseToRecyclerview(apiResponse: ApiResponse?) {
    rvItem.apply {
        layoutManager = _layoutManager
        apiResponseList.add(apiResponse!!)
        itemAdapter = activity?.let { ItemAdapter(apiResponseList, it) }!!
        adapter = itemAdapter
    }
    Log.e("assign", isLoading.toString())
}
```

MainPresenter.kt

```
override fun makeACall(date: String?) {
    //view.showProgressDialog()
    date?.let { restModel.fetchApiResponse(this, it) }
}

fun processDateWithoutMakingACall(date: String) {
    val apiResponse = processRawJson(sp.getString(date, "").toString())
    passResponseToView(apiResponse)
}

override fun processRawJson(rawJson: String): ApiResponse {
    val parser = JsonParser()
    val rootObj = parser.parse(rawJson).asJsonObject
    var ratesObj = JsonObject()
    var ratesKeys: Set<String> = HashSet()
    val ratesArrayList: ArrayList<Currency> = ArrayList()
    val rootKeys = rootObj.keySet();
    var baseValue = ""
    var dateValue = ""
    for (key in rootKeys) {
        if (key == "base")
            baseValue = rootObj.get(key).asString
        if (key == "date")
            dateValue = rootObj.get(key).asString
        if (key == "rates") {
            ratesObj = rootObj.get(key).asJsonObject
            ratesKeys = ratesObj.keySet()

        }
    }
    for (key2 in ratesKeys) {
        Log.e("ratesKey", key2)
        Log.e("ratesValue", ratesObj.get(key2).asFloat.toString())
        ratesArrayList.add(Currency(key2, ratesObj.get(key2).asFloat))
    }
    saveRawJsonIntoSp(rawJson, dateValue)
    return ApiResponse(baseValue, dateValue, ratesArrayList, false)
}

override fun passResponseToView(apiResponse: ApiResponse?) {
    view.hideProgressDialog()
    view.assignResponseToRecyclerview(apiResponse)
}
```

RestModel.kt

```
override fun fetchApiResponse(presenter: MainPresenter, date: String) {
    job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val response = userService.getCurrenciesForDate(date)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                val rawJson = response.body()
                val apiResponse = presenter.processRawJson(rawJson)
                presenter.passResponseToView(apiResponse)
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: May I ask what's the use case for this?

Comment: Recyclerview in CurrencyListFragment loads exchage rates from specific day. When i scroll at the end of this recyclerview, exchange rates for older days are populated (there is added new element to list of recycler view). And now here is the clue. When I do this scroll I want to add just one element instead of 2-3 (but sumetimes is also 1).

Answer (score 1):

Try out the SnapHelper, it might slow layout manager to make more callbacks and stop overloading